# Moving Validations from one sandbox to production using changeSets

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, validation, code-coverage

Thinking to move code Validation rules from sandbox to production. Do I have to check for the code coverage?

Comment: Yes. I think some of your test classes might get failed and hence your code coverage will fall down due to new Validation rules. Though you can run test classes by passing validation rules but that is not a good practice.

Comment: Deploying your validation rules to a pre production environment will provide you with a safety net to catch unit test failures by the introduction of new rules. Salesforce will make sure all unit tests are run with the Production deployment.

Comment: Seriously? This might be the most complete lack of research effort I have yet seen on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Deifinitely.

Since the validation rules may impact DML Operations heavily. Hence suggested.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be about `Validation Rules`, but rather validation via `Apex`. Coverage is not strictly required to deploy the config version.

Comment: thats right @AdrianLarson ...but my point was not about coverage...i was thinking of avoiding any run-time DML issues by not running related test classes when deploying any code/configurations..